# Python, using variables from __init__ in a parent dir

Tags: python, import, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a website I've been writing using Flask, although for this question I do not think that's relevant. This is the folder structure I'm working with. Rhea is the name of the project and the parent directory.

```
Rhea
|- Scripts
    |-script1.py
|- Static
|- Templates
|- __init__
```

My problem is I declare variables inside my init that I need to use inside script1.py. How do I import these into script1.py?

For reference this is my init file

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_appconfig import AppConfig
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.sqlachemy import SQLAlchemy

from .frontend import frontend
from .nav import nav
from .models import User

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db', 'userdb.db')
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db')
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL = True
SECRET_KEY = --SNIP--

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

AppConfig(app)
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(frontend)
nav.init_app(app)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6060, debug=False);

return app
```

The variables I need is db, SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, and the SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO.

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0):

*A* solution is to append the the `sys.path` with the `Rhea`'s package parent directory. But it's ugly.

```
# cript1.py 
import os
import sys

rhea_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(rhea_dir)

import Rhea
print Rhea.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```